# How do I ground an old two wire cable for use in a structured media centre

Tags: electrical

My home was built in 1945.  The wiring has been replaced in most of the house but some sections still contain cabling with only two wires in them.  Black(hot) and white (neutral?).  I need to install a structured media centre to handle some cat 6 cables and tidy up what my phone and Internet service provider wants to install.  I installed a Leviton 47605-28w box.  I have fed the two wire cable into a plastic gang box at the base of the SMC. The SMC is inside the house and is mounted on an exterior wall. The homes grounding rods are on the opposite side of this wall (less than 5'away).  Is there a safe and legal way to ground the outlet and the SMC without having to install new cabling ( way too much drywall to remove) or run it all the way back to the main panel?  Thank you.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Do you want the ground for safety or is it essential for your media enclosure to work?

Comment: Ground for my safety and the media equipment.  Don't want any fires either. :)

Comment: Based in Vancouver BC

Comment: The ground wire doesn't have to run with the other wires in the circuit, or even on the *same* circuit. Just figure out the most convenient path (walls, crawlspace, attic) and fish a green or bare ground wire to a convenient grounded junction box or the service panel. Make it the same gauge as the other wires in the circuit.